# Row vector whose element is Kronecker product of two matrices

Tags: xml, android-layout

I would like to know if any one knows how to rewrite in a matrix form a row vector whose element is a kronecker product of two different matrices. This is to say
(A1(x)B1, A2(x)B2,...,An(x)Bn), where each matrices Ak, k=1,...,n, is a square (pxp) matrix, whereas each Bk is a (qx1) column vector.

Thanks for the help,
Budhi

I can only reoresent ut as a row vector only. Bit it is not mathematically operational.